# XPages Extension Library and REST control

Tags: rest, xpages

I've only recently started experimenting with the REST control in the latest Xpages Extension library.

I've been able to create a REST control to return the contents of a view:
https://www.example.com/RESTApp.nsf/data.xsp/companies

and the fields in a document by passing in the UNID:
https://www.example.com/RESTApp.nsf/data.xsp/company/unid/8C4DA14484C699B488257F0800691B2C

Taking this a step further, I would like to create a REST API that can be used by another IT group within my company to access customer data (say based on customer ID). If I have a Domino view with customer data sorted by customer ID, what would my REST control look like if the external group wanted to consume the REST service by passing a customer ID along instead of a UNID?

Would I need to create a custom REST service? Any examples to get me started would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think you need to create a custom REST service.

If you are looking for the URL to pass, it would be something like this: http://localhost/jobs10.nsf/TriggerNav.xsp?/hotSheets?rName=Alex

And us something like:

var uriString = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();
var unidString = @RightBack(uriString, "rNamee/");

to get the parameter you pass. Pass that into your GET, and it should work.

I did a Notesin9 about this, and the link here as the full application. It writes into a nsf, but you can adopt it to

http://stentorian.us/stentorian/DominoHerald.nsf/%24%24OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=28500727329491B687257E5900744A14&action=editDocument

Cheers,
Brian

Comment: Thank you Brian. That works perfectly for what I need now.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on how your API should look like to the outside. You have 2 considerations:

- How shall the calling parameters look like
- How should the data look like

`?ReadViewEntries&OutputFormat=JSON&RestrictToCategory=customerID` when you categorize your view would be the easiest way to have some (readonly) rest API.

I however would start with a [Swagger API definition](http://swagger.io) definition negotiated with the other group. This approach is called "contract first development". Then build a custom bean based REST service. Since you have access to the URL, you can grab the part after your rest name (e.g. data.xsp/company/companyID ).

Use my [blog article](http://notessensei.com/blog/2014/10/custom-rest-service-in-xpages-using-a-service-bean.html) as starting point.

In a nutshell: your bean needs to extend the `CustomServiceBean`. Pretty straightforward.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.RestServiceEngine;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomServiceBean;

public class CustomSearchHelper extends CustomServiceBean {

@Override
public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {

    HttpServletRequest request = engine.getHttpRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    // Your code goes here!

    }
}
```

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Brian's solution met my immediate need. For a more long term solution I will definitely look into what you propose. Appreciate the input. Cheers!